# Android Context.bindService always returns false and ServiceConnection object is never triggered

Tags: java, android, service

I have followed the [Local Service example](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#LocalServiceSample) provided by Google, but my `Context::bindService(...)` always returns false and there is `ServiceConnection::onServiceConnected` is also never called.

I understand that `Context::bindService()` returns immediately, but my `ServiceConnection` object is never triggered.

I don't know if these apply

1. My activity is running inside a tabHost and I was wondering if that can affect service binding in any way.
2. The Service itself may have a problem, but I can call start service to the same service with the same `Intent` and it works as expected.

Does anyone have experience with this? Please help me out.

Thanks,
P.S. I am targeting Android 1.6

Comment: Use `adb logcat`, DDMS, or the DDMS perspective in Eclipse and look for *warnings* at the point in time of your binding. A failed binding usually results in a warning.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

So I finally figured it out. It turns out that [TabSpec cannot bind to activities](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2483#c2)

> Using getApplicationContext().bindService instead of just bindService on your
>   activity solves the problem as it is using the higher level application context.

Hope this helps someone!

Comment: THnaks, i had exactly the same problem :)

Comment: Had the same problem with fragments and this helped!

Comment: It took me an hour to find this post... You're a life-saver.

Answer (score 3):

I now this is old, but I had a slightly different problem. I refactored the package of my project. So the name changed of the files, but Eclipse did not update the manifest file. So, I manually fixed the manifest file and changed the name of the package there as well.

Comment: thank you! argh, forgetting to update that manifest can drive a man insane :( I wish there was an error in the log indicating this...