# Binding to service always returns false

Tags: android, binding, service

I am trying to bind to a service, but the bind service method always returns false. I believe the problem is in my connection. When I import the location of the LocalBinder class (in the service) I dont get any compile errors but the bindService call is still false.

Service information:

```
//binder for client
private final IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();

//client class binder
public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
    ServiceA getService() {
        // Return this instance of LocalService so clients can call public methods
        return ServiceA.this;
        }
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    return mBinder;
}

//called when service is created
public void onCreate(){
    super.onCreate();
    Toast.makeText(this,"ServiceA is started",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Connection:

```
 private ServiceConnection connect2A = new ServiceConnection() {

    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className,
            IBinder service) {
        // We've bound to LocalService, cast the IBinder and get LocalService instance
        LocalBinder newBinder = (LocalBinder) service;
        mainService = newBinder.getService();
        bound = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName arg0) {
        bound = false;
    }
};
```

Initial calls:

```
    @Override
protected void onStart(){
    super.onStart();
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ServiceA.class);
    startService(intent);
    boolean check = bindService(intent,connect2A,0);
    Toast.makeText(this, "Return from check is: " + check, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    //program does get to this point, but binding fails
}
```

the AndroidManifest.XML file:

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".ServiceTest2Activity"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
<service android:enabled="true" android:name=".serviceA" />
</application>
```

Comment: Do you have the Service declared in your AndroidManifest.xml? <service android:name=".YourService" />

Comment: Yes, it is set up as:        
 </activity>
 <service android:enabled="true" android:name=".serviceA" />
    </application>

Comment: Why are you calling startService prior to calling bindService on the same intent? This seems redundant. Have you tried eliminating this call?

Comment: Yes, the startService call STILL returns FALSE

Comment: I assume the import com.ajc2990.ServiceA.LocalBinder; is required as the LocalBinder is in the Service class. When this line is removed, Eclipse gives an error.

Comment: Yes, you need that. Have you tried debugging to see if onBind(Intent arg0) is even getting called?

Comment: Got it, the XML file had a discrepancy in the name of the service. I assume I need to add the same line for each additional service I add?

Comment: Yes. For each service you have you must declare it in the manifest. I suggest up-voting @DanJ's comment on the other answer since he was correct in assuming that the spelling of your service name was wrong.

Comment: Check the context which you are using to bind. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2914921/android-context-bindservice-always-returns-false-and-serviceconnection-object-is

Answer (score 0):

Some ideas:

-What class is the onStart() method in?  I bind to my services in onCreate().

-Do you perhaps need to pass `Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE` to the bindService call?  e.g.

```
boolean check = bindService(intent, connect2A, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

-As the other commenter suggests, you should post the relevant snippets from your AndroidManifest.xml.

-You should put some trace/toast in the `onServiceConnected` method so you know if it is getting called.

Comment: Adding BIND_AUTO_CREATE had no change, the bind still = false

Comment: <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".ServiceTest2Activity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
 <service android:enabled="true" android:name=".serviceA" />
    </application>
</manifest>

Comment: onStart is in the main activity class. I moved the relevant code to the onCreate method, same problem.

Comment: Is your problem case sensitivity in your service name? i.e. "ServiceA" vs "serviceA"?

Comment: And I do have a Toast in the connection, but the Eclipse IDE gives an "is not applicable" and won't compile.

Comment: AndroidManifest.xml is case sensitive, and my Eclipse Helios project does NOT give me a warning if I change my service name to have the wrong case.