# android licensing could not bind to service

Tags: android, android-lvl

I'm trying to implement android licensing and keep getting an error in the log that could not bind to service.

I am having similar problem as this link

[Android Context.bindService always returns false and ServiceConnection object is never triggered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2914921/android-context-bindservice-always-returns-false-and-serviceconnection-object-is)

but the solution did not work.  I have gone all the way back to the android sample app and I'm getting the same error no matter what context I try and when I make no changes to the sample.  Does the service need to be in the manifest, it is not in the sample.  I was thinking maybe it had something to do with the library?  I have tried this with the library using 1.5 and then with android 2.1 and 1.5 in the emulator, in all cases same issue, service will not bind...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I determined the issue was not my source code, it was the ways I was trying to test it.  For the simulator, you need to be using either Google API 8 or higher or have market installed to get the service to bind, I just used Google API 8 and it seems to work fine.  On my device I am still not sure exactly why it is failing, it is version 2.3 and it works fine with my primary account logged in, but the other logins do not seem to work that I added in the developer console.  I suspect it is because the APK is not yet uploaded, but still not sure why it works for my account but not theres...